# How to display fields one below one in suitelet?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I want to display fields one below one in a suitelet. How it can be achieved? Please help!!

Expected output:

field1

field2

field3

field4

field5

field6

field7

Total

I am not able to display fields like this.one below one

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Field` instances in an `N/serverWidget.FieldGroup` and set the `FieldGroup`'s `isSingleColumn` property to `true`.

If that doesn't work, you can use each `Field` instance's `updateBreakType()` method to add a break after each `Field`.

Comment: Thanks erictgrubaugh for response! but now I want to create summary box type box and add those fields to that. Can we do that in suitelet?